OpenSSL 1.1.x and libffi7 not found since this morning while running python in gcloud cloudshell (looking for persistent solution)
It seems that an update has happened on the cloudshell which has me and my colleagues unable to do local deployment of our app engine app (that uses a flask framework).
I get the following error in ssl.py:
ImportError: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Installing an older version of openssl and libffi7  solves our issues temporarily. However, it does so in a way that does not persist on the cloudshell.
I have tried updating pandas and pip to see if that would solve compatibility issues (iteratively update the package in which the error was raised). but that didn't work for pip and the error in pandas was just replaced by an error in a different import for which updating did nothing.
Does anyone have a suggestion on how to solve this issue in a way that persists on the cloudshell?

You need to update your software - OpenSSL 1.1.1 hit end-of-life last September and is being replaced with OpenSSL 3.x.x.
